# CSS 3 Stop Rotate Animation After N seconds after page load

Tags: html, css

I don't have much knowledge in css3 and I got this code fragment that makes a div spin infinitely.

```
.spin {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 0.4s linear infinite;
  animation: rotation 0.4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-100%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-100%) rotate(45deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0%      { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50%     { -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); }
    100%    { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}

@keyframes rotation {
    0%      { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50%     { transform: rotate(-180deg); }
    100%    { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

I want to stop the rotation after a couple of seconds but I don't know what to change. I tried changing `infinite` to `3` but it stopped and placed my div somewhere else. I need a smooth stop and retains the div original position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxfo3pdc/1/)**

the element was moving because of the `translate`

code :

```
.spin {
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 background:red;
 -webkit-animation: rotation 0.4s linear 3;
 animation: rotation 0.4s linear 3;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform:  rotate(45deg);
}
```

you should know that the `infinite` is a value of the `animation-iteration-count` property which specifies the number of times an animation should be played. so not the seconds.

if you want to stop after N seconds use `animation-duration` and i suggest you divide the animation declaration into parts, like this :

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxfo3pdc/3/)**

for ex you want the spin to rotate for 2 seconds, if you set `animation-duration` to 2 seconds, the whole animation  will take 2 seconds to complete, and that's not what you want. You want your `spin` to rotate fast for 2 seconds, so you need to calculate the `animation-iteration-count` like this 2second/animation-duration

say you want 1 rotation to be completed in 0.5s, you set the `animation-duration:0.5s` and then `animation-iteration-count` to 2s/0.5 = `4`

code :

```
spin {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform:  rotate(45deg);
  animation-name:rotation;
  animation-delay:0s;
  animation-duration:0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count:4;
  animation-fill-mode:backwards;
}
```

for more info about animations, read here : **[CSS3 animation Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)**

Comment: Nice, works perfectly. And thanks a lot for the explanation. Two thumbs up!

Comment: glad i could help. i also edited the answer with a link for more information about CSS3 animations